# How can I add a multidimensional panel to estimate TFP (year, id, region) in R?

Tags: econometrics, production-function, productivity, stata, r

I'm not sure about adding **fixed effects** for the variables year,id,region (using the `estprod` library) as in this [paper](https://publications.iadb.org/en/do-imports-of-intermediate-inputs-generate-higher-productivity-evidence-from-ecuadorian-manufacturing#:%7E:text=Do%20Imports%20of%20Intermediate%20Inputs%20Generate%20Higher%20Productivity%3F%3A%20Evidence%20from%20Ecuadorian%20Manufacturing,-Author&text=Particularly%2C%20imports%20can%20generate%20an,inputs%20in%20their%20production%20processes.) using LP stimator.

[image]

> In the STATA forum ( [#18](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1357861-new-on-ssc-prodest-module-for-production-function-estimation?p=1394261#post1394261) [#19](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1357861-new-on-ssc-prodest-module-for-production-function-estimation?p=1394298#post1394298); `prodest` library) it seems that to add fixed effects I have to create dummies *Control* parameter.
>
> > qui tab year, gen(dy) // generate one dummy per year

> > prodest log_y, free(log_lab1 log_lab2) state(log_k) proxy(log_investment) va met(op) poly(4) reps(40) id(id) t(year) control(dy*)

> To make a third panel **PLM** I found in [STATA](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/2095-three-dimensional-panel-data-regression?p=2120#post2120) as in [R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47479982/11570343)

## Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(estprod)

data = read.csv("data_tfp.csv")

data = data %>% 
  mutate(v = 1,
         rgn = region,
         group = group_indices(., id, region),
         grp = group) %>% 
  spread(rgn, v, fill = 0) %>% #generate one dummy per region
  arrange(id, year)

md0 = estprod::levinsohn_petrin(data,
                                formula = y ~ l | k | m | a+b+c+d,
                                id = "id",
                                time = "year",
                                reps = 10,
                                gross = T)
summary(md0)
```

## My data

[here](https://mega.nz/file/9kpCFIya#XBkF5nXr8fR5hc3AjWrsfyWsDtnCkv8vq-iBxusJzSk)